# Create a custom gridview design

Tags: java, android, layout

I need to do like this image, I tried gridview but it's not working,it gives me more than 3 images in the same line.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2rlP.png)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

and this is my gridview :

```
   <GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="3" >  </GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with numColumns = 3.

```
<GridView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="3"/>
```

Comment: I assume the first set of xml code is your grid item layout. If so, your textview is never visible as its pushed out by the match_parent height of imageview. Not the answer to your question, just pointing out an issue here.

Comment: so, can you  give me some ideas to start ? I tought using 3 linear layoutin every linear layout I put 3 image view to solve this, without using grid view, what do you think ?

Comment: What is the kind of data you are showing your grid? Is it constant or does it keep changing.

Comment: like the image above it s constant, this is the home of the application so it's fixe, what I need to it's adapt the size of views in gridview like the image

Comment: I'm assuming you need a 3x4 fixed grid. For three columns, set numColumns = 3 in xml. Then, in your array adapter, dynamically set the height of your grid item layout to one fourth the height of screen.